# Collect numbers within an iframe and sum those values

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping

In the example we have `1 - 0`, the idea would be to collect these two numbers, sum the two values and have this value as an answer to show it on the page. In this case, sum `1+0` with the result `1` and update this collection in real time for the value to change immediately if the numbers change.

`Radar 1` value example: `21082334`

[image]

**How could I make this collection on real time and sum them up inside my HTML script?**

> **Note: I didn't do tests because I don't know how to scrape inside an HTML script. My scraping knowledge is only with Google Sheets
> formulas, which don't help the project at all.**

My HTML Script:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         {
         box-sizing: border-box;
         }
         .column {
         float: left;
         }
         .left {
         width: 360;
         }
         .middle {
         width: 360;
         }
         .right {
         width: 360;
         }
         .row:after {
         content: "";
         display: table;
         clear: both;
         }
      </style>
      <script language="JavaScript">
         let intervalID
         window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            intervalID = setInterval(refreshIt, 500); // refresh every 0.5 secs
         })
         
         function refreshIt() {
            if (!document.images) return;
            // if want to stop the interval from repeating
            // if (!document.images)  clearInterval(intervalID)
            document.images['Chart 1'].src = ChartBar1.value;
            document.images['Chart 2'].src = ChartBar2.value;
            document.images['Chart 3'].src = ChartBar3.value;
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="column left">
            <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter">
               <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 1</button>
               <input type="text" name="url" id="url" style="width: 283px;" />
            </form>
            <iframe id="the-frame" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               (function () {
                "use strict";
                var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter'), url = document.getElementById('url'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame');
                url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + url.value;
                };
               }());
            </script>
            <form method="post" target="imgChart1">
               <input type="submit" value="Chart 1" />
               <input type="text" id="ChartBar1" name="ChartBar1" style="width: 286px;"><br>
            </form>
            <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 1">
         </div>
         <div class="column middle">
            <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter2">
               <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 2</button>
               <input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" style="width: 283px;" />
            </form>
            <iframe id="the-frame2" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               (function () {
                "use strict";
                var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter2'), url = document.getElementById('url2'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame2');
                url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + url2.value;
                };
               }());
            </script>
            <form method="post" target="imgChart2">
               <input type="submit" value="Chart 2" />
               <input type="text" id="ChartBar2" name="ChartBar2" style="width: 286px;"><br>
            </form>
            <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 2">
         </div>
         <div class="column right">
            <form action="" method="post" id="url-setter3">
               <button type="submit" name="submit">Radar 3</button>
               <input type="text" name="url3" id="url3" style="width: 283px;" />
            </form>
            <iframe id="the-frame3" width="347" height="282" src=""></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
               (function () {
                "use strict";
                var url_setter = document.getElementById('url-setter3'), url = document.getElementById('url3'), the_iframe = document.getElementById('the-frame3');
                url_setter.onsubmit = function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    the_iframe.src = "https://sports.staticcache.org/scoreboards/scoreboards-football/index.html?eventId=" + url3.value;
                };
               }());
            </script>
            <form method="post" target="imgChart3">
               <input type="submit" value="Chart 3" />
               <input type="text" id="ChartBar3" name="ChartBar3" style="width: 286px;"><br>
            </form>
            <img src="https://www.futebolnaveia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/betfair-app.png" name="Chart 3">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are restricted to access iframe contents, because of cross origin policy enforced by browsers. You can use postmessage api to send and recieve messages accross the iframe. check more : http://dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/postmessage/

Ofcourse, you should be owning the iframed site as well, else you wont be able to change code there.

Another solution, to circumvent this restriction, is to use a server, to get response from the iframe url, parse the html on server itself, read whatever you want and return the result to your website with a rest api.

Another solution is to make a chrome extension that would inject a content script into the iframed page, this script would then read and communicate the result to your page, though the post message api, same as in first solution

Comment: yup.. iframes need to be same origin as the window to access them in the first place.. and accessing variables inside iframes are like `someIframe.contentWindow.someVariable`